# Duplex label and tics in gnuplot (epslatex)

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I am trying to draw some graphs with reading some values from the file, using epslatex - gnuplot (version 5.0 patchlevel 1), as follows:

```
# gnuplot.gp
set term epslatex
set output "figure.tex"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

set nokey
set size square
set xrange [0:1.0]
set yrange [0:1.0]

do for[idLine = 1 : 4 : 1]{
    a1 = system("cat data.dat | awk 'NR == ".idLine." {print $1}'")
    a2 = system("cat data.dat | awk 'NR == ".idLine." {print $2}'")

    plot x**a1 + a2 with lines lt 1 lc rgb "black"
}
```

and the data is

```
# data.dat
1.0 0.0
2.0 0.0
3.0 0.0
4.0 0.0
```

Though I could managed to draw figure I've wanted, there is still a problem that the labels are getting bolder than a single plot (please see figures below, I hope that the image quality is enough to tell the difference ...).
It seems that these phenomenon occur due to the duplex letters of the several times plotting.

I have tried several way to avoid this problem, but non of these didn't work.
Is there any smart way to avoid this problem?

[image: Graph with number of plots]

[image: Graph with a single plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can read the whole file into a variable and extract the parameters with `word`. Then you can iterate over all parameter with `plot for ...` which generates only a single graph with several plots:

```
# gnuplot.gp
set term epslatex
set output "figure.tex"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

parameters = system("awk '!/^#/' data.dat")
set xrange [0:1]
plot for [i=1:words(parameters):2] x**word(parameters, i) + word(parameters, i+1) with lines notitle
```

The `awk` call removes comment lines from your input file. If it doesn't have any comments, you could also use `parameters = system("cat data.dat")`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, beautiful solution.